# Cholesky on a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to solve a linear system using Cholesky decomposition, but I get stuck when solving the system.

Here is the matrix :
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 &  \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & -1 & 2 &  \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots &\ddots & \ddots & -1 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

(Sorry, it is quite ugly but I don't manage $\LaTeX$ and matrices well).

So for the  Cholesky matrix ($T$ such that $TT*=M$) I find  a matrix with a lower double diagonal with $-\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{k
+1}{k}}$.

So I'm stuck there, I can't manage to find a solution to $Tx=B$ with $B= \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & \cdots & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}*$.

I find $x_1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $x_{k+1}=(-1)^k \sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k+2}} + \sqrt{\frac{k}{k+2}}x_k$ but I need a not-reccurent forme to apply the step with $T*$.

How can I do ?

Comment: That's the Cartan matrix of type $A_n$, which has determinant $n+1$ and its inverse is pretty easy to write down. Why do you need Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: @Marc : I'm a begginer in matrices, don't know about Cartan matrix and the goal of the exercise is to use Cholesky decomposition.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to solve the system, we can do even better than by using Cholesky.

Let's start by defining the lower bidiagonal matrix $D$ with $1$ on the diagonal and $-1$ on the lower diagonal.
When applied to a vector, it gives the first element followed by the one-step difference of all elements (like the `diff` function in Python-numpy, R, Matlab, ...). Its inverse is the lower triangular matrix of all ones that, when left-multiplied to a vector, gives its cumulative sum (like `cumsum` in Python-numpy, R, Matlab, ...). In particular $D^{-1}u=1_{n}$, where $1_{n}$ is the column vector of all ones and $u$ is the column vector with one in the first element and zero elsewhere.

We can see that $DD^{\top}$ is almost equal to $M$, differing only in the top left element, which is $1$ instead of $2$. We can therefore easily "fix" this product as follows:
$$
M = D\,D^{\top} + u^{\top}u.
$$

We can use the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) (which is a special case of the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)) to invert $M$ as follows:
$$
M^{-1}
=
(D\,D^{\top} + u^{\top}u)^{-1}
=
D^{-\top}D^{-1} - \frac{D^{-\top}D^{-1}u\,u^{\top}D^{-\top}D^{-1}}{1 + u^{\top}D^{-\top}D^{-1}u}
=
D^{-\top}D^{-1} - \frac{D^{-\top} 1_n 1_n^{\top} D^{-1}}{1 + 1_n^{\top}1_n}
=
D^{-\top} \left(I_n + \frac{1}{1 + n} 1_n 1_n^{\top} \right) D^{-1}.
$$

By following the last expression from right to left we can now see that $M^{-1}x$ can be computed taking the cumulative sum of $x$, then subtracting from the result its sum divided by $n+1$ and finally taking the cumulative sum in reverse order.

In Python this could be written as:

```
def solveM(x):
    y = np.cumsum(x)
    y -= sum(y) / (len(y) + 1)
    y = np.cumsum(y[::-1])[::-1]
    return y
```

In R:

```
solveM <- function(x) {
  y <- cumsum(x)
  y <- y - sum(y) / (length(y) + 1)
  y <- rev(cumsum(rev(y))) 
  return(y)
}
```